# specify asp.net core custom route

Tags: routes, asp.net-core

I would like to specify a custom route like so:   localhost:4444/code, where code is a random code assigned to a Course. Currently the default routing forces the Controller/Action/Id route. I would like to bind the above to Courses/Details/Code, but would rather not specify /Courses/Details in the route to make it short.

Answer (score 0):

The following routes will work for you.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "course_code", 
        template: "{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Courses", action = "Details"});
});
```

Those routes will map as follows:

```
HomeController.Index()

    localhost:4444                
    localhost:4444/home          
    localhost:4444/home/index   

CoursesController.Details("math101")

    localhost:4444/math101                 
    localhost:4444/courses/details/math101
```

See also: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/routing.html